# django tagging - filter by tag

Tags: python, django, view, filter, tags

I'm on a [free-time project](https://bitbucket.org/JackLeo/django-persona), and I have this model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    <..>
    tags = TagAutocompleteField()
```

`TagAutocompleteField()` is same as `TagField()` from [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) witch is simple `CharField` so `print post.tags` will give `'one two three'` instead of `['one', 'two', 'three',]`.

Also i have a view:

```
def tagged(request, tag_id):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, pk=tag_id)
    post_list = Post.objects.all() \
                .filter(tags__split__in=tag) \                                                          
                .filter(is_published=True) \
                .order_by('-time_publish')
    return render_to_response('plugins/persona/list.html', {
                              'post_list': post_list,
                              })
```

The problem is that i cannot filter all the posts that have specific tag since tags is `charField` i've tried to use `split()` but filters does not allow it.

People suggest to use this function to get tag list:

```
def get_tags(self):                                                                                 
    return Tag.objects.get_for_object(self)
```

but yet i cannot it use in filters also.

How should i get all the posts that have same tag? Usual way with tagging is to get objects by tag but if tags are used by few applications it may give more than posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`regex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex)

```
.filter(tags__iregex=r'\b%s\b' % tag)
```

Comment: Possibly just about any world problem could be solved with regex... Thanks it works :)

Comment: There should be note that mySQL regex differs from Python.